# How to remove duplicatates from wtforms QuerySelectField

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, wtforms

In my Flask form I want to have a drop down list of unique items.Depending on what is selected will filter which items will appear in a second drop down (using javascript for this).

I have a database table something like this:

| Category | Sub-category | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Application | Can't log in | Incident |
| Application | Error | Incident |
| Application | Install | Request |
| Application | Remove | Incident |
| Database | Optimise | Request |
| Database | Corrupt | Incident |

and so on. So in the Category column there are multiple entries of the same name.
Currently when I populate the QuerySelectField using this:

```
category = QuerySelectField(label='Category',
                               query_factory=lambda: Classification.query.filter_by(selectable=True),
                               allow_blank=True,
                               get_label='category', id='category', blank_text=u'Select a category...'
                                )
```

I get a list of everything in the Category column. But I only want to list one of each item. How can I do this?

I thought to use SelectField instead of QuerySelectField but could not figure out how to dynamically create the choices[].

Comment: I ended up figuring out how to do this using a SelectField and dynamically creating the choices[] for that field. But I'm still curious to know if it can be done with QuerySelectField because with the SelectField there is no option to start with a blank option. Which I need as I'm populating another SelectField dynamically with javascript depending on what is selected in this first SelectField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this if anyone else has this same use case.

I changed this:

```
category = QuerySelectField(label='Category',
                               query_factory=lambda: Classification.query.filter_by(selectable=True),
                               allow_blank=True,
                               get_label='category', id='category', blank_text=u'Select a category...'
                                )
```

to this:

```
category = QuerySelectField(label='Category',
                            query_factory=lambda: Classification.query.filter_by(selectable=True).distinct(Classification.category),
                            allow_blank=True,
                            get_label='category',
                            id = 'category',
                            blank_text = u'Select a category...'
                            )
```

The trick was adding the `distinct(column you need to be distinct)` part. In my case `distinct(Classification.category)`